# Java Application running as web service communicating with Java EE app on Glassfish

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, glassfish-3

I have a stand alone Java application that needs to get information (string data) from a Java EE application, running on a Glassfish 3.1 Application server. I have created a web service for my Java app, but I'm wondering how I could achieve communication with the Java EE glass fish app (using servlet?).

I hope to have a method on my app that can be called from, for example, a client running on glassfish (and vice-versa). This method would have something like a String array as parameter, so that I would be able to pass the data between the apps.

*Note*: I am unable to deploy my app on Glassfish, since we are trying to achieve separation till we are sure the application I am developing will not cause Glassfish to crash ( we currently have other critical apps running on Glassfish). Also note that this is all taking place on the same machine.

Comment: If you cannot deploy code to the server, what would you expect to talk to then?

Comment: Talk to an app running on glassfish that will be pushing data to my app.

Comment: Then consider adding information to your question about how _that_ app expects to be talked to.  In other words, what is its public API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should develop a web service and deploy it on Glassfish within your existing application. You can do this via a Servlet based web service, or a Session Bean web service, whichever is more appropriate for you.

You will then create a web service client against that web service for your Java app, and integrate it appropriately with calls to the servers via the web service.

Of course, this should all be done against development servers, not your production servers. Glassfish can be deployed pretty much anywhere: your machine, another machine, a VM, in "the cloud". Not having a development server available for, well, development is **unacceptable**. There is no way you can determine if your app will "crash Glassfish" unless you can test it.

To quote the esteemed Donald Knuth: "I have only proved it correct, not tried it."

Get a test server, develop against it. Move forward.

Comment: Thanks, I will try implementing your proposed solution and provide feed back here. Also, I do agree, having a development server is the way to go. In my case though, i require the production servers as that data I am getting from them is 'live alarm data' from network device elements that are being managed via the Java EE applications running on this glassfish server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the URL class.
try this url [Java URL example](http://crunchify.com/java-url-example-getting-text-from-url/)

> This may help